# How to check if a consumer group has fully consumed a topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

if there is not a util already or application that does it, i would be interested in recommendation on how to check that all the topics of a consumer group have been fully consumed?

What is the best route to implement such a solution ?

Are there utility in the kafka eco-system that would help with that task ?

Comment: "fully consumed" is not accurate term in Kafka world, thats because messages are not removed from the topic once consumed. I believe you are interested in the consumer group lag, which is the delta between the latest offset written and the latest offset consumed by the consumergroup

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want consumer lag, as shown by `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` output. All lags of zero mean the consumers have committed the end-offset and/or your consumers are processing faster than any producer to those topics (which is not always true, so lag may never truly reach zero)

While each consumer is running, you could check that polling has returned zero records, or in the librdkafka API, the consumer throws an "end of partition" code when you've reached the end. Then you would need to aggregate this information for all partitions of each topic, as well as by `group.id`.

You could see if the [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) HTTP API has the information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what i was after. That burrow app is impressive btw.